# Should I try to salvage and attract attention to old question or ask new question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a problem that I want to ask a question about. But there already is a question on that topic, but it is broad and was poorly asked until I edited it. From the tags it seems that that asker was using a different technology than me, but the question was so poorly asked it wasn't clear. Naturally the question got some very vague answers and they don't really help me.

I honestly don't know if my question would get different answers (and thus not be a duplicate) or if the vague, hinting answers of the other question actually is what I need to do (my question is very entry level in that technology I suspect).

I'm not even 100% sure the question is entirely on topic and not a question for another SE site (it might be Server Fault instead).

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an existing question involves a technology other than what you are using, then you are free to ask it.

To avoid confusion of being a duplicate question, try to mention the technology in the Question Title.

Take an example.

If a question exists, "*How to save data in database involving multiple tables?*" and it involves *mysql*, then you can ask a question with title "*How to save data in database involving multiple tables in mongoDB?*"

It will help in avoiding confusions regarding whether it's a duplicate or not.

But keep in mind, if two questions are too much related then it might get duplicate.

Like a question "*How to hide a div using onclick event in Jquery?*" can be easily considered a duplicate to the question "*How to hide a div using onclick event in javascript?*".

A brief table of **DO**s and **DON'T**s:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          Existing Question            |           Your Question          |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   DO(s)                                                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Title: How to save data in database   | Title: How to save data in       |
|        involving multiple tables?     | database involving multiple table|
|  Tag: Mysql, Query                    | in mongoDB?                      |
|                                       | Tag: mongoDB                     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Title: Write a query in mysql to      | Title: How to delete data from   |
|        delete data from two tables    | multiple table simultaneously    |
|        simultaneously                 | using stored procedures in mySQL?|
|   Tag: Mysql, Query                   | Tag: stored-procedure, mysql     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Title: How to fetch response from     | Title: Fetch data from server    |
|        server side by ajax method     | side via ajax response using     |
|        using $.ajax()                 | $.post() method.                 |
|    Tag: PHP, JQuery, Ajax, javascript | Tag: PHP,JQuery, Ajax, $.post    |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   DON'T(s)                                                               |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Title: How to hide a div using        | Title: How to hide a button using|
|        javascript?                    | jquery?                          |
|  Tag: javascript.                     | Tag: javascript, jquery          |
|                                       |                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Title: What is the difference between | Title: Which is better to use,   |
|        get and post method in PHP?    | get or post method in PHP?       |
|  Tag: get, post, PHP                  | Tag: get, post, PHP              |
|                                       |                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Hmmm, I guess asking is my best option. Just hope it won't get closed as duplicate.

Comment: Why the downvote? I would appreciate if someone corrects me.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks. I will keep that in mind this onward. :) Also, keep your comment here. Its a great feedback. :) I appreciate it.